# Magento2 - using getFinalPrice() or getData('final_price')

Tags: magento2

I want to know which one is the best way to do? since the $product->getFinalPrice() return the same result as the $product->getData('final_price')

Thank you

Comment: Both are same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search the function `getFinalPrice()` in **vendor** folder & see what it does

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty = null)
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || $this->_getData('final_price') === null) {
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
    } else {
        return $this->_getData('final_price');
    }
}
```

That's the code you may miss if you call directly `getData('final_price')`, which would be an alias of `$this->_getData('final_price')` in above code

Sometimes there will be no difference, as the property value will be already set when you call `getData()` but if function exists it is always better (unless you want to specifically avoid the call) to use it

This applies for all object properties which you can access through `getData()` function